# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^{4}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^{4}}\, dx$$
Define
$$I\left ( a \right )=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\arctan \left ( ax \right )}{1+x^{4}}\, \mathrm{d}x\Rightarrow I'\left ( a \right )=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{2}}{\left ( 1+a^{2}x^{2}\right )\left (1+x^{4}  \right )}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
but it seems too complicated,is there another way for it?

Comment: this is a simple integral if you are familiar with the residue theorem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do (here we do $x\mapsto 1/x$ and use the fact that $\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2-\arctan x$)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^4}\,dx&=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x(\pi/2-\arctan x)}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^4}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\bigl[\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2)\bigr]_0^{+\infty}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: symmetry based solutions rock! (+1)

Comment: sry,didn't see your answer just now

Comment: @Renascence_5. Don't worry, I know how it feels. You get a +1 from me since I agree with your solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the best way!

Let $x\rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x}$, we get 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^{4}}\, \mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\arctan\left ( \dfrac{1}{x} \right )}{1+x^4}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
notice that
$$\arctan x +\arctan\left ( \dfrac{1}{x} \right ) =\frac{\pi}{2}$$hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^{4}}\, \mathrm{d}x&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x\left (\arctan x +\arctan\left ( \dfrac{1}{x} \right ) \right )}{1+x^{4}}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi }{4}\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x}{1+x^{4}}\, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
then you can take it from here.